# "layout run failed" on Ext.Panel.tbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new learner to extjs 4.0 and tried some examples from learning materials.
One example doesn't work as expected with "layout run failed" with following code:

```
var panel = Ext.create("Ext.Panel",{
    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
    layout:"auto",
    height:500,
    width:400,
    autoLoad:{
        url:"Component.txt",
        renderer:"component"
    },
    renderer:"component",
    tbar:[
        {text:"load", scope:panel, handler:function() {
                panel.loader.load({
                    url:"Component1.txt",
                    renderer:"component"
                });
            }
        },
        {text:"remove", scope:panel, handler:function() {
                panel.loader.load({
                    url:"Component1.txt",
                    renderer:"component",
                    removeAll:true
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});

component.txt:
{xtype:'panel',height:100, width:200, html:"Original Component"}

component1.txt:
{xtype:'panel', height:100, width:90, html:"New Component"}
```

I tried to remove the `tbar` section and it works.
So I believe the problem is with `tbar`.
Ext JS version: ext-4.2.1.883
Browser: Firefox 25.0.1, Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with `scope: panel`. You cannot use the variable `panel` inside the definition of that variable. You code says:

```
panel = Ext.create( .... scope: panel ...);
```

This makes no sense. Maybe `scope: this` will do what you are looking for. If not, you have to rethink the way you define your class.

Anyway, the recommended way to do this is to define your class in a dedicated file, and stick to the [MVC recommendations](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I tried with your suggestions (scope:this) and still it doesn't work.